# How to write SQL query for getting rows which must have some specific combination of values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this.

```
Image_ID    Person_Ref  FileName    Effect_Ref
1            1           EU000101.jpg            1
2            1           EU000106.jpg            6
3            2           EU000201.jpg            1
4            2           EU000202.jpg            2
5            2           EU000203.jpg            3
6            3           EU000301.jpg            1
7            3           EU000306.jpg            6
8            4           EU000401.jpg            1
9            5           EU000501.jpg            1
10           5           EU000504.jpg            4
11           5           EU000505.jpg            5
12           6           EU000601.jpg            1
13           6           EU000604.jpg            4
14           6           EU000605.jpg            5
15           7           EU000701.jpg            1
16           7           EU000704.jpg            4
17           7           EU000705.jpg            5
18           8           EU000801.jpg            1
19           8           EU000806.jpg            6
```

**Now I want to get all those Person_Ref which must have Effect_Ref, let say 1, 2, 3**

I tried some thing like this but I know it is not what I want

```
select distinct * from Images where Effect_ref IN (1,2,3) order by Effect_ref
```

Comment: it gives me all the rows which have Effect_Ref 1 or 2 or 3 but i want only that specific person_ref which must have  Effect_Ref 1 , 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the instances of the records (*which is equal to the number of supplied parameter in `IN`*) that matches your condition. Try this one,

```
SELECT Person_REF
FROM tableName
WHERE Effect_REF IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY Person_REF
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8f661/2)

Comment: not working, see Image_ID 15 16 17, it has Effect_Ref 1, 4 ,5 could you write a query to get Person_Ref which has Effect_Ref 1, 4 ,5

Comment: @sHaXahid [what's the problem with this query?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8f661/3)